# Understanding ensemble learning and its implementation in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, machine-learning, decision-tree, ensemble-learning

Is [ensemble learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) an example of many instances of a particular classifier, for example Decision Tree Classifier; or is it a mixture of couple of classifiers such as Neural Networks, Decision Tree, SVM and so forth?

I have looked into this [wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating#Description_of_the_technique) description on `Bagging` an ensemble learner. It says that:

> Bagging leads to "improvements for unstable procedures" (Breiman, 1996), which include, for example, neural nets, classification and regression trees, and subset selection in linear regression (Breiman, 1994).

I am little confused about this description. I also have looked into MATLAB's [implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ensemble-methods.html#bsvk5ue) of ensemble algorithm. For example this one:

```
load fisheriris
ens = fitensemble(meas,species,'AdaBoostM2',100,'Tree')
```

`meas` and `species` are inputs of the [`fitensemble`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitensemble.html) function. Here in this example it is using `AdaBoostM2` weak learner of type `Tree` and is using `100` of them. How can this simple instance of this function is being addressed to show that ensemble learning is used to combine different classifiers such as `Neural Net, KNN, Naive Bayes` together?

Can anybody explain what is ensemble learning actually and what is MATLAB trying to do in its implementation of `fitensemble` function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The basic idea of [ensemble learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) is to combine multiple models to improve prediction performance. They are considered *meta-algorithms* designed to work on top of existing learning algorithms. There are various approaches:

- [Bagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) (stands for **B**ootstrap **Agg**regation) generates a set of models each trained on a random sampling of the data ([bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29) [resampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28statistics%29): sample N instances with replacement). The predictions from those model are combined/aggregated to produce the final prediction using averaging.
- [Random Subspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_subspace_method): the idea is to randomize the learning algorithm, such as picking a subset of features at random before applying the training algorithm (think [Random Forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) for example). Each model is trained on data projected onto a randomly chosen subspace. The outputs of the models are then combined, usually by a simple majority vote.
- [Boosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_%28machine_learning%29): also built on the concept of voting/averaging multiple models, however it weights the models according to their performance. It constructs models in an iterative manner, where new models are encouraged to become "experts" for instances misclassified by earlier models. Boosting works best if the base learning algorithm is not too complex (weak learner). There are several variants of this algorithm ([AdaBoost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost), [LogitBoost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogitBoost), GentleBoost, [LPBoost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LPBoost), etc..).
- [Stacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Stacking): combines the predictions of multiple base learners (usually of different types: kNN, ANN, SVM, etc..), not using voting as before, but using a meta-learner (a model trained on the output of the base models). So the predictions of the base learners are fed as input data to the meta-learner in the next layer to produce the final prediction.

---

[`fitensemble`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitensemble.html) is a MATLAB function used to build an [ensemble learner](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ensemble-algorithms.html) for both classification and regression. It supports three methods: bagging, boosting, and subspace. You can choose between three kinds of available weak learners: [decision tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) ([decision stump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_stump) really), discriminant analysis (both [linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) and [quadratic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_classifier)), or [k-nearest neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) classifier.

> **Note:** Except for `Subspace` method, all boosting and bagging algorithms are based on [tree learners](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/decision-trees.html). Subspace can use either [discriminant analysis](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/discriminant-analysis.html) or [k-nearest neighbor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classification-using-nearest-neighbors.html) learners.

For example, the following code trains a *decision tree ensemble* classifier (consisting of 100 trees) using the [AdaBoost](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/adaboost.html) method fitted on the training dataset `X` with corresponding classes `Y`.

```
ens = fitensemble(X, Y, 'AdaBoostM1', 100, 'Tree')
```

(the `M1` part indicates a binary classifier, there is an extended `M2` version for multiclass problems)

Comment: you can learn more about ensemble methods by browsing questions and answers on [stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ensemble)

Comment: Thanks for the edits, haha, really appreciable. I was confused about ensemble learning, and after learning about it, was too lazy to make the edits.

Comment: @JohnAndrews: Not really. According to [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitensemble.html#inputarg_Learners), it must be one of the three supported types: discriminant analysis, kNN, or decision tree. You can however customize them by passing a weak-learner template where you can set their respective options (ie. `templateDiscriminant`, `templateKNN`, `templateTree`). You can also supply a cell-array of weak-learner templates.

Comment: Just a note to the last line, the `M1` is binary classifier, `M2` is multiclass. Source: [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcensemble.html)